# How can you drag a Delphi StringGrid row without fixed any columns?

Tags: delphi, drag-and-drop, tstringgrid

If you set the option goRowMoving = True you can move rows in a Delphi TStringGrid by dragging them in the fixed column. Is there a way to drag rows from non-fixed row columns? Like say in a StringGrid without any fixed columns.